# VSCode で WCF の開発は可能?

Tags: vscode, wcf

タイトル通りですが、VSCode で WCF の開発は可能でしょうか？

Comment: このような.NET CLIで使える？ツール [.NET の追加ツールの概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/additional-tools/) があるようですので、これらが使えれば一助になるのでは？ こちらはVisual Studio用の説明。[WCF 開発ツールの使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/wcf/using-the-wcf-development-tools) ただし、.NET Core以降ではWCFはクライアント向け用途しかサポートされていないし、それも互換性維持用らしいので情報やノウハウは乏しくなる一方だと思われます。

Comment: ちなみに何か出来そうな記事があったので参考になるかも。[Create a WCF Web Service Reference in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65919187/9014308), [How to reference a WSDL file using Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41496773/9014308)